# CALCULAR PORCENTAJE EN SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo una tabla donde cada registro es una compra y debo mostrar el porcentaje de compras por item

tengo el siguiente codigo

```
SELECT item_type, count(*), tl.total, count(*)/tl.total promedio
from compras,
(select count(*) total from compras) tl
GROUP BY item_type, tl.total
```

y me sale 0 en porcentaje.. que estoy haciendo mal?  deberia ser la division de la segunda y la tercera columna

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pon la estructura de tu tabla

Comment: En el ejemplo, numéricamente `count(*) < total` por lo que siempre la división será menor que `0`. ¿No será que está redondeando el valor al entero más cercano, `0` en todos los casos? De todas formas el promedio no se calcula de esa forma, prueba hacer la operación al revés: `tl.total/count(*)`. Si siempre da números enteros, prueba usar `CAST(tl.total/count(*) AS FLOAT) promedio`.

Comment: la estructura de mi tabla es esta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
 T.item_type,
 T.Cantidad,    
 (T.cantidad * 100.0 / (SELECT count(*) FROM compras)) AS porcentaje
from
(SELECT 
 item_type, 
 count(*) as cantidad, 
from compras
group by item_type)T
```

La **consulta interna** nos va a devolver una relación donde por cada **item_type** se obtenga su total. Sobre esta consulta es que hacemos el cálculo del porciento proyectando el **item_type**, su **cantidad**, y el tercer campo sería el **porcentaje** utilizando la **regla de 3**, dividiendo la parte por el total y multiplicando por **100**.

Comment: gracias asi si lo resolvi.. la proyeccion primero sobre la subconsulta de las ventas.

Answer (score 2):

Tu consulta es correcta, el problema ya te lo adelantaron el los comentarios, es  que una división entera retorna un número entero:

```
SELECT  1/2     'DivisionDeEnteros', 
        1/2.0   'DivisionFloat'

DivisionDeEnteros   DivisionFloat
                0        0.500000
```

En tu caso, los `COUNT` son siempre valores enteros, de ahí lo que ocurre en tu consulta. Lo más sencillo podría ser algo así `(tl.total*1.0)`:

```
SELECT item_type, 
       count(*), 
       tl.total, 
       count(*)/(tl.total*1.0) promedio
       from compras,
            (select count(*) total from compras) tl
       GROUP BY item_type, tl.total
```

Comment: no.  desafortunadamente no me lo resolvio con el truco de multiplicar por el numero float ni tampoco con el cast de la primera solucion, desconozco la razon.. porque si lo calcula correcto lo cual pude comprobar dividiendo al reves... y si tenia un error de sintaxis.. no era promedio era porcentaje

Comment: Revisa lo paréntesis, también puedes hacer `count(*)*1.0/tl.total`